# How can i display this objects in angular

Tags: angular, object

Below is the image of JSN data:

[image: receiving json data from api]

web.service.ts

```
 myQuote = 'http://quotes.rest/qod.json';

 getQuotes(){
  return this.http.get(this.myQuote).subscribe(data => {
    // data = const quotes;  
    console.log(data)
  });
}
```

home.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'messages',
  template: ' here {{contents?.quotes[0].quote}}'
})

export class MessagesComponent {
constructor(private webService: webServices){}

showQuotes(){
    this.webService.getQuotes();
    var items = {}
  }
  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.showQuotes())

  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the JSON in the text format

Answer (score 0):

Based on assumption, as per your screenshot:

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of data.contents.quotes">
    <div> {{obj.propertyName_that_you_want_display }} </div>
    <h2>Options:</h2>
    <div *ngFor="let tag of obj.tags">
        {{tag}}
    </div>
</div>
```

[`A Working Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxuqmo)